# t-sql compare trailing average with current data

Tags: t-sql

I have a task to get the trailing average of the number of records received in 
past 10 months and the number of records in this month. For example, in the set 
of records below, the average of records per month for last three months is 4.33.
and the number of records of in this month is 3.
Hence the result expected is,

[image: Result]

```
declare @recordsReceived table (id int, dob date)

INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (1,'2020-01-01')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (2,'2020-01-08')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (3,'2020-01-17')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (5,'2020-02-03')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (6,'2020-02-09')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (7,'2020-02-16')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (8,'2020-02-21')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (9,'2020-02-28')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (10,'2020-03-01')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (11,'2020-03-07')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (12,'2020-03-21')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (13,'2020-03-28')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (14,'2020-04-03')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (15,'2020-04-09')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (16,'2020-04-30')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (5,'2020-02-03')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (6,'2020-02-09')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (7,'2020-02-16')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (8,'2020-02-21')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (9,'2020-02-28')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (10,'2020-03-01')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (12,'2020-03-21')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (12,'2020-03-21')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (13,'2020-03-28')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (14,'2020-04-03')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (15,'2020-04-09')
INSERT @recordsReceived VALUES (16,'2020-04-30')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
Select * From (
  Select count(month(dob))*1.00/count(distinct(month(dob))) As [TAVG] 
  from @recordsReceived 
  Where month(dob)  < (Select max(month(dob)) from @recordsReceived)) A

 ,
 (Select count(month(dob)) [Current]
 from @recordsReceived 
 Where month(dob)  = (Select max(month(dob)) from @recordsReceived)) B
```

Comment: What about the previous 10 months; does the first `select` need a `between` `max -1` and `max -10` in the `where`

Comment: @PeterSmith- Yes Peter filter with month number.